# How do I concurrently process Reactor Kafka Streams by Topic and Partition with Auto Acknowledgement?

Tags: apache-kafka, rx-java, reactive-programming, kafka-consumer-api, project-reactor

I am trying to achieve concurrent processing of Kafka Topic-Partitions using Reactor Kafka with auto-acknowledgement. The documentation here makes it seem like this is possible:

http://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/milestone/reference/#concurrent-ordered

The only difference between that and what I am attempting is I am using auto-acknowledgement.

I have the following code (relevant method is `receiveAuto`):

```
public class KafkaFluxFactory<K, V> {

    private final Map<String, Object> properties;

    public KafkaFluxFactory(Map<String, Object> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public Flux<ConsumerRecord<K, V>> receiveAuto(Collection<String> topics, Scheduler scheduler) {
        return KafkaReceiver.create(ReceiverOptions.create(properties).subscription(topics))
            .receiveAutoAck()
            .flatMap(flux -> flux.groupBy(this::extractTopicPartition))
            .flatMap(topicPartitionFlux -> topicPartitionFlux.publishOn(scheduler));
    }

    private TopicPartition extractTopicPartition(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record) {
        return new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition());
    }
}
```

When I use this to create a Flux of Consumer Records from Kafka with a parallel Scheduler (`Schedulers.newParallel("debug", 10)`), I see that they all end up getting processed on the same Thread.

Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

After quite a bit of trial-and-error plus some rethinking of what I want to accomplish I realized I was trying to solve two problems in one bit of code.

The two things I need are:

1. In-order processing of Kafka Partitions
2. Ability to parallelize the processing of each partition

In trying to solve both with this piece of code, I was limiting downstream users' abilities to configure the level of parallelization. I therefore changed the method to return a Flux of GroupedFluxes which provides downstream users with the correct granularity of determining what is parallelizable:

```
public Flux<GroupedFlux<TopicPartition, ConsumerRecord<K, V>>> receiveAuto(Collection<String> topics) {
    return KafkaReceiver.create(createReceiverOptions(topics))
        .receiveAutoAck()
        .flatMap(flux -> flux.groupBy(this::extractTopicPartition));
}
```

Downstream, users are able to parallelize each emitted GroupedFlux using whatever Scheduler they wish:

```
public <V> void work(Flux<GroupedFlux<TopicPartition, V>> flux) {
    flux.doOnNext(groupPublisher -> groupPublisher
            .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .subscribe(this::doWork))
        .subscribe();
}
```

This has the desired behavior processing each TopicPartition-GroupedFlux in-order and parallel to other GroupedFluxes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it executes sequentially at least in your consumer. To do a parallel consuming you should convert you flux to `ParallelFlux`

```
public ParallelFlux<ConsumerRecord<K, V>> receiveAuto(Collection<String> topics, Scheduler scheduler) {
        return KafkaReceiver.create(ReceiverOptions.create(properties).subscription(topics))
            .receiveAutoAck()
            .flatMap(flux -> flux.groupBy(this::extractTopicPartition))
            .flatMap(topicPartitionFlux -> topicPartitionFlux.parallel().runOn(Schedulers.parallel()));
    }
```

After in your consumer function if you want to consume in parallel way you should use method such as:

```
void subscribe(Consumer<? super T> onNext, Consumer<? super Throwable>
            onError, Runnable onComplete, Consumer<? super Subscription> onSubscribe)
```

Or any other overloaded method with `Consumer<T super T>` onNext arguments.
If you just use method as below you will consume flux in sequential way

```
void subscribe(Subscriber<? super T> s)
```

Comment: @Mr.E.Gas Also you can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44588357/2055854 to better understand how `Flux` works

Comment: Thank you for your input on this; It doesn't _quite_ solve my problem, but I found a sort of multi-faceted answer to what I was trying to accomplish that I will answer my question with.

The reason your answer doesn't quite solve my problem is that it ends up parallelizing the processing of the GroupedFlux and therefore might result in out-of-order processing, which is undesirable for my use cases.